# Why RefCell's `into_inner` requires a move?

Tags: rust

I have a situation where I have to move a struct from one object to another through a `&mut self`. Take a look:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    //no copy trait
    device: Device
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn finalize(&mut self) {
        //error: cannot move since I borrowed 
        let interface = InterfaceBuilder::new(self.device)
    }
}
```

First of all, why I cannot move something out of a borrowed mutable reference? Borrowed mutables are exclusive, there's no chance another code is looking into it.

Well, to address this problem I changed to

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    //no copy trait
    device: RefCell<Device>
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn finalize(&mut self) {
        //error on `self.device`: cannot move out of `self.device` which is behind a mutable reference
        let interface = InterfaceBuilder::new(self.device.into_inner())
    }
}
```

I know why the error occurs:

```
pub fn into_inner(self) -> T
```

calling `into_inner` makes `self.device` move. Why `RefCell` simply does not have an implementation `pub fn into_inner(&mut self) -> T`? I don't see a problem.

Comment: In your first version, _there's no chance another code is looking into it_ **now**, but the original owner might look into it **later**, after `finalize` returns and releases the mutable borrow.

Comment: if `into_inner` didn't consume, then what would be in the `RefCell` afterwards?

Comment: Your `finalize` method should take ownership of `self`: `pub fn finalize (self) { … }`

Comment: My guess is that you don't have control over the signature of `finalize()` (e.g. since it's in a trait you do not control), but you can control `MyStruct`. If this guess is correct, then one solution would be to use `Option<Device>`. You can move out of an `&mut Option<_>` using the `take()` method, which leaves `None` in the option.

Comment: Regardless of whether I guessed your problem correctly, it would be nice if you could clarify the question to explain your requirements a bit more. It's important to show your attempts at _solving_ the problem, but explaining the actual problem you are trying to solve is important as well to get useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot move out of a mutable reference because that would leave the original object incomplete.

Consider this code:

```
struct MyStruct {
    s: String
}

fn finalize(f: &mut MyStruct) {
    let _x = f.s; //error E0507!
}

fn main() {
    let mut my = MyStruct {
        s: "hi".into()
    };
    finalize(&mut my);
    println!("{}", my.s); //what should this do?
}
```

Then, `RefCell::into_inner(&mut self) -> T` has the same problem. You could call it twice in a row and you would get two `T` values where before there was only one. And that, for a non `Copy` type is impossible.

If you want this function to consume the inner value, probably it should consume the outer value too:

```
fn finalize(f: MyStruct) {
    let _x = f.s;
}
```

If you really want to move a value out of a mutable reference, you must leave something valid in its place. The easiest way is to declare an `Option` and use `take()` to steal and replace it with a `None`:

```
struct MyStruct {
    s: Option<String>
}

fn finalize(f: &mut MyStruct) {
    let _x = f.s.take();
}
```

Naturally, `Option::take` returns an `Option` so that if you call it twice, the second time you get `None`. If you are positive you have a value you can do `take().uwnrap()`.

Alternatively, if your field type is `Default` you can use `std::mem::take` that replaces it with a default-created value:

```
struct MyStruct {
    s: Vec<i32>
}

fn finalize(f: &mut MyStruct) {
    let _x = std::mem::take(&mut f.s);
}
```

PS #1: there is `Cell::take(&self) -> T`, but only if `T` implements `Default`. It works just like `std::mem::take` but with a non-mutable reference.

PS #2: there is also `unsafe fn ManuallyDrop::take(slot: &mut ManuallyDrop<T>) -> T`, that is intented to be used in advanced `drop` implementations. But it is `unsafe` so it should never be your first option: if you call it twice you will get *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `std::mem::replace` is also an option if `T: Default` or `Option<T>` are unsavory.